# Android: Draw Custom TextView on Canvas

Tags: android, textview, android-canvas, drawable

I have following TextView

```
public class Cube extends TextView {

Context mContext;

Drawable background;//Hintergrund des Blocks
char mLetter;//Buchstabe des Blocks
int x, y;//Koordinaten des Blocks

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public Cube(Context context, char letter, int _x, int _y) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mLetter = letter;
    background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.cube);
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    this.setText("" + letter);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    else
        this.setBackground(background);
}

public void drawCube(Canvas canvas){//how to draw now!? This is called from a separate thread in SurfaceView
}

}
```

If I call following in drawCube():

```
    background.setBounds(x, y, x + 20, y + 20);
    background.draw(canvas);
```

it just draws the backgroundDrawable. But how can I draw it with the text/the letter inside? That it looks like this: (The background ist the canvas, the orange and white one is the Background and the "A" is the letter/text)

[image]

**EDIT: Code at 21.09**
This is my (shortened) thread:

```
public class CanvasThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder mSh;

private ArrayList<Cube> mCubes;

private Canvas mCanvas;
private Context mContext;
private boolean mRun = false;
private boolean mDown = false;
private boolean newCube = false;
public CanvasThread(SurfaceHolder sh, Context context){
    mSh = sh;
    mCubes = new ArrayList<>();
    mContext = context;
}

public void run(){
    while(mRun){
        mCanvas = null;

        try{
            mCanvas = mSh.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSh){
                mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                newCube = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < mCubes.size(); i++){
                    if(mCubes.get(i).getSpeed() > 0)
                        newCube = false;
                    if(mDown) {
                        if (mCubes.get(i).moveDown(feld)) {
                            mDown = false;
                        }
                    }
                    //mCubes.get(i).invalidate();
                    //mCubes.get(i).requestLayout();
                    mCubes.get(i).draw(mCanvas);
                }
                if(newCube)
                    addCube();
            }
        } finally {
            if(mCanvas != null){
                mSh.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addCube(){
    Random r = new Random();
    Cube cube = new Cube(mContext, mBuchstaben[r.nextInt(29)], r.nextInt(10), 0, mCanvas);
    mCubes.add(cube);
}
```

}

This is my (shortened) fragment which uses the canvas/surface view:

```
public class KlassischFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

SurfaceHolder sh;
SurfaceView sv;

private CanvasThread thread;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_klassisch, container, false);
    sv = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    sh = sv.getHolder();
    sh.addCallback(this);
    sh.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread = new CanvasThread(sh, getContext());
    thread.setRunnable(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    //thread.setRunnable(false);

    while(retry){
        try{
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch(InterruptedException ie){
            //Immer wieder versuchen
        }
        break;
    }
    thread = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `canvas.drawText()`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Why do you need the text to be in the drawable? I am not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: Can you uplod an inage of how you want the cube to look? It is kind of hard to imagine how you want it to look

Comment: So again why do you need it be in a drawable? You can just draw the text on top of the cube (it is a square).

Comment: Then add your `onDraw` call when you are drawing the Text.

Comment: What do you mean? Where to add this?

Comment: You said that you tried drawing the text on top of the square. I assume you did it in `onDraw()` callback of `Cube.class`. I want to see how you have done so I can help you with put it at the centre

Comment: This should not be the way you do this. What you should do is override `onDraw()` in the view and then you can call ` invalidate()` on the view to be redrawn. Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: try adding `requestLayout()` as well

Comment: I will write a gist for you when I get back home

Comment: Tried this too, didn't help.
Thats nice thank you!

Comment: Added to the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to draw a text on top of a square. Some of the values hardcoded but you should be able to make them dynamic.

```
public class Cube extends View {

    private final static String TEST_STRING = "ABC";
    private Paint mBackgroundPaint;
    private Paint mTextPaint;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public Cube(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    public Cube(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public Cube(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public Cube(Context context) {
        this(context, null, -1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Just for demo purposes this should be calculated properly
        int desiredWidth = 100;
        int desiredHeight = 100;

        setMeasuredDimension(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int savedCount = canvas.save();
        drawRectangle(canvas);
        drawText(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedCount);
    }

    private void init() {
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        // This need to be adjusted based on the requirements that you have
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(20.0f);

    }

    private void drawRectangle(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mBackgroundPaint);
    }

    private void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        // For simplicity I am using a hardcoded string
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(TEST_STRING, 0, 1, rect);
        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        float x = (w - rect.width()) / 2, y = ((h - rect.height()) / 2) + rect.height();
        canvas.drawText(TEST_STRING, 0, 1, x, y, mTextPaint);


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works (with some changes) perfectly!
The only thing that still exists, is that I have to call onDraw manually by calling cube.draw(canvas);

Comment: You should not do that. `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` should be doing this for you automatically.

Comment: This does not work. It just shows nothing then. Or do I have to add the "cube" to the canvas before in any way?

Comment: Ah ok. You are not using it in conventional way of adding it to the root layout (or through xml).  If you do not do it hat way then you have to take of drawing it yourself.

Comment: Okay then I can do it the way I am doing it at the moment right?

Comment: I guess. I am not sure what is the purpose of your app. But if it is working then it is fine. :)